# javascript adding to string not wokring

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Im trying to get a link where I have to add a countrycode to a link.

Im trying this:

```
var link = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha?codes=" + myData;
```

Where myData is defined by:

```
var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
var myData = div.textContent;
```

dom-target:

```
<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
<?php
$output = $_GET['id']; 
echo htmlspecialchars($output); 
?>
</div>
```

Where the $_GET['id'] is a code like FR or NL.

but for some reason when I console.log() it, it comes out with the link and underneath that I see the countrycode, indicating that it hasnt added the countrycode to the link.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Without your markup (which needs to be posted to make a [mcve]), it's impossible to say, but the first line of the docs for `textContent`: _The Node.textContent property represents the text content of a node and its descendants._ (Note that last part).

Comment: try `var link = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha?codes=" + myData.trim();` otherwise going to need more context. let me know how it goes.

Comment: I added more contect im just trying the answers

Answer (score 0):

`var link = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha?codes=" + myData.trim();`

the `.trim()` will remove and spaces

if that doesn't work you can try `myData.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");` this will remove line breaks.

good luck

Comment: it says that trim() is not a function

Comment: that would suggest either you have an error in you code, or myData is not a string.

Comment: try myData.toString() first

Comment: @Brad `.textContent` always returns a string, so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @PauldeKoning What does `console.log(myData)` show?